# can you store negative zero in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, negative-zero

In javascript, there is such thing as negative zero. What will MongoDB do with this value?

Comment: that's true. but if this knowledge is documented somewhere on the internet, it would be even easier and faster. So if someone can document their answer here it would benefit later generations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested. It does store -0 as -0.